# How to resize a polygon in km?

Tags: openlayers-2

I have a polygon on my map and I want to resize it in that way I add  X km to all of the vertexes. Any idea?

Comment: Resize relative to what?  Adding N kilometers to the y dimension and the x dimension of every vertex will simply move the polygon farther away from the zeropoints of the x and y axes of the projection (for latitude, the equator, for example).

Comment: You do realise that for most polygons this will result in a modified shape?

Comment: I want to do the same like this:

obj.geometry.resize(2, obj.geometry.getCentroid() );

instead of 2 there will be x-km. I'm sorry for the misunderstanding...

Comment: Closely related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/29893.

Answer (score 3):

The spatial operation you need is called BUFFER and is implemented in most geographical database managers

Comment: +1 for this answer... although a general question is, why don't you just redraw the polygon to the specifications that you want?

Answer (score 1):

if you use geodjango on server side, you can use [buffer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#django.contrib.gis.geos.GEOSGeometry.buffer) method in Topological Methods.

```
polygon.buffer(1000) # 1 km buffer for your polygon
```

i hope it helps you...